# In Node.js, does a required module load multiple times if requested multiple times?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

An application I'm building is reliant on several `.json` configuration files. Because I need the same configuration data to be persistent across the application's modules, I've created an individual `config.js` module where I parse the `.json` files and export a singular object:

```
var fs = require("fs");
module.exports = {
    a: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./config/a.json")),
    b: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./config/b.json")),
    c: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./config/c.json"))
};
```

Considering that I `require` the `config.js` module in multiple other modules, will the parsing of the json files run each time the config module is required? Or is Node smart enough to run the `JSON.parse()` function only the first time and subsequently use the cached results?

Comment: Once required, the module is cached, I  had to decache them on one of my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node will cache modules the first time they are loaded, so the code will only run once.

http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching

There's some other interesting information in there, such as for the purpose of config, you can `require()` JSON files. It's a bit easier than using `fs`.